# Como adicionar um transition (fade-in) nesse exemplo?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Tenho um site que quando vc passa o mouse por cima do item ha uma troca de foto. porem essa troca é imediata. gostaria de adicionar um efeito transition, tipo um hover transition 1s. é possivel?
estou ultilizando o mouseover e mouseout.

eu chamo esse metodo pra mudar foto.

```
function mudaFoto(foto){
    document.getElementById("icone").src = foto;
}
```

Comment: Ideia: Use duas divs,  uma por cima da outra,  cada uma com uma imagem,  posicionadas assim com CSS. Com CSS3 vc faz o hover da de cima fazer uma transição pra opacity 0.  Faria um exemplo pra vc se eu tivesse na frente do computador e com tempo livre,  mas tô escrevendo do cel e tb estou pegado com meu TCC.  Pelo menos deixo essa ideia pra se vc quiser tentar ir por esse caminho ou pra quem tentar responder a pergunta usando dessa forma.  Trocando o src somente não sei se seria possível.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo a ideia do Antonio Alexandre, fiz esse pequeno exemplo utilizando apenas CSS:

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
}
.image img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.image img:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}
.image img:nth-child(1):hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
.image img:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=32&bg=55c1e7&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMAGEM%201&w=200&h=200">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=48&bg=55c1e7&txtclr=ffffff&txt=IMAGEM%202&w=200&h=200">
</div>
```

Resumindo, dentro da `<div class="image">`, as duas imagens estão com `position: absolute;`, ocupando o mesmo espaço e posição.

Com `z-index`, defini qual imagem sobreporia a outra. A que fica por cima, leva o atributo `transition: 1s;`.